# React Native with expo av- recording audio stops on Android 12 after picking up a phone call

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am developing a recording app in React Native. For that, I use [expo-av](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-av). I've noticed recently that on Android 12 when a user picks up a call, the app keeps recording but when listening to it later, there is silence while the user was on the phone, but also after he hung up till the end of the recording. On older versions of Android, there is silence while the user was on a call, but it starts capturing audio again when he hangs up. Any idea how to fix that it keeps capturing audio after the user hangs up?

I am on expo 45, btw.

Answer (score 0):

In new android version (>=12) permissions are changed. Please look at the [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Comment: There are quite a few of them. Any idea which one I should look at?

Comment: I am not sure but you can look these permission to give you idea about your work ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I've changed TARGET_SDK to version 31 (Android 12) and it seems to be working now.